# Print next word after pattern match for two strings in same line for one file in se

Tags: awk, sed, grep

i have different lines in one file .I want to achieve the output as below. I want to print the next word  after aaaa and test words with delimiter ,.

Input is

```
Line Aaaa orange test match 

Colour Aaaa banana test sun

Ball Aaaa guava test Saturday 

Basket Aaaa tomato test sunset
```

Output has to be

```
Orange ,match

Banana ,sun

Guava, Saturday 

Tomato,sunset
```

Could anyone please help on this

I have tried using sed ,grep commands but i  didnt get the expected output

Comment: What have you tried? Please share your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`awk` solution**

Assuming you want to ignore lines where "Aaaa" does not occur, the following `awk` process should achieve your needs (if the relative positions of"Aaaa" and "test" are constant - see edit below):

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i=="Aaaa") {print $(i+1) ", " $(i+3); next}}' file
```

**explanation**

Each line of `file` is processed (by default) as white-space separated fields. A loop examines each field for the required `pattern` ("Aaaa") and (if found) prints the values of the next field, the required comma, and the value of the final required field.

**Edit**

For cases where the position of "test" may also vary, *providing* "test" is never before "Aaaa"*, the following procedure should work:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if ($i=="Aaaa") {line= $(i+1) ", "; } if ($i=="test") {line=line $(i+1); print line;next}}}' file
```

It will need reworking if "test" can come before "Aaaa" as follows:

```
awk '{partA=partB=""; for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if($i=="Aaaa") partA=$(i+1); if($i=="test") partB=$(i+1); if(partB && partA) {print partA ", " partB; next}}}' file
```

This version requires both "Aaaa" and "test" are present but they can be in any order on the line.

(each) **tested on `file`:**

```
Line Aaaa orange test match

Colour Aaaa banana test sun

Ball Aaaa guava test Saturday

Basket Aaaa tomato test sunset
```

**output** (for all three versions)

```
orange, match
banana, sun
guava, Saturday
tomato, sunset
```

(using GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Comment: Thanks for the help
But in the above the Aaaa and test are random in the same line.                                            Line Aaaa orange dress test match

Colour Aaaa banana sweep won test sun

Ball Aaaa guava test Saturday

Basket Aaaa tomato test sunset

Comment: Do you mean the position of the last word you want might change? I'll modify the procedure to specifically choose the word following 'test'

Comment: Yes the Aaaa and test word positions are not same in all the lines

Comment: @Sai I've added an edit with the revised procedure. It still requires that "test" comes after "Aaaa", is that the case?

Comment: Always Aaaa position is before test position

Comment: I made two edits. The second will handle different positions as long as "test" is after "Aaaa", the third will work for any order

Comment: I have tried the above command but it is not working.  I used the same command but it didn't fetched the words

Comment: post the error message and I'll have a look. Also what `awk --version`?

Comment: Actually when I ran the above second command ,it didn't gave any outputs.i mean it didn't fetched the words .       Version is Awk 4.2.1,

Comment: make sure the filename with the data follows the `'` of the awk command. To make sure run `awk '1' file` - that should print the source file to terminal if everything is right. Then replace between the `'  '` with the procedure.

Comment: Yes I ran the awk '1' file .it prints the complete string. But when I replace with second command no output i received

Comment: ok, the other thing to check is that `$i=="Aaaa"` and `$i=="test"` exactly match (including case) the corresponding words in the file (and are bounded by white space). If the fields contain more than exactly "Aaaa" and "test" try replacing `$i=="Aaaa"` and `$i=="test"` with `($i ~ "Aaaa")` and `($i ~ "test")`. The `~` means "contains" rather than the `==` which means "exactly equals"

Comment: what parts are the search pattern and which do you wish to keep (for that example line)

Comment: actually, my input is like

:10A:SEC XZGGSH//COMETY REG U :10B::AGGGG//DSS/F150000,SEED
:10A:SEC ABGGSH//COMETY QWE U :10B::AGGGG//DSS/950000,ASW
:10A:SEC AGYGGSH//UTMETY SIYU :10B::AGGGG//DSS/950000,IUO

I want to extract the output after SEC and before // and for other word after DSS/ need to extract price.
output :

XZGGSH , 150000 

ABGGSH, 950000

AGYGGSH,950000

Comment: actually, my input is like
 :10A:SEC XZGGSH//COMETY REG U :10B::AGGGG//DSS/F150000,SEED :10A:SEC ABGGSH//COMETY QWE U :10B::AGGGG//DSS/950000,ASW :10A:SEC AGYGGSH//UTMETY SIYU :10B::AGGGG//DSS/950000,IUO I want to extract the output after SEC and before // and for other word after DSS/ need to extract price. output :                                           
                                                     XZGGSH , 150000   
 ABGGSH, 950000 AGYGGSH,950000.

Comment: That's a bit more complicated and will need sub strings to be extracted from fields. My advice would be to spend a while formulating a precise question, including several REAL example lines and expected output, and re post as a new question.

Comment: Okay sure i will repost the question thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

perl, using look-behinds:

```bash
perl -nE 'if (/(?<=aaaa )(\w+).*(?<=test )(\w+)/i) {say "$1,$2"}' file
```